# Postback issue in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have an asp.net label control with its Visible property set to false. In the code-behind I'm setting its visibility to true/false based on whether the user has logged in or not. A weird behavior is that on postbacks, the code-behind executes and sets the value of the label's visibility to whatever, and then the markup executes and sets the label's visibility to false. On non-postback requests, the status set by the code-behind is *not* overwritten. Pardon my ignorance, but am I missing something important?

Comment: can you please post your code to clarify?

Comment: it sounds like you are coding to the wrong events and stepping on the page lifecycle.  post code so we can have a look.

Comment: I've taken care of checking IsPostback on PageLoad. Code is insignificant here. My question is- Why does the markup execute after the code-behind? Is there something fundamental I am missing?

Comment: Did you do a trace and see what happens? or when it breaks?

Comment: -1: Why have you ticked an answer that is completely unrelated to how the problem was solved?

Answer (score 5):

Get to know the page lifecycle, and when the various page events are fired by the runtime.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Also,  I don't think the code is insignificant.  If it were coded properly, you wouldn't be experiencing this problem.  Put it up here and let us have a look.

Answer (score 2):

There's no code posted so you might already have this.

are you wrapping everything in your Page_Load method with

```
if(!Page.IsPostback)
{
    // your code here.
}
```

?

Comment: Yeah, I've taken care of checking IsPostback.

Answer (score 1):

does your Label has a EnableViewState="false" attribute?

Learn more on this attribute at http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_viewstate.asp

Comment: It was just one of those queer things a developer faces occasionally. Weirdly, a machine restart fixed it. Would you believe it?! Thanks for your inputs anyway.