# asp.net linkbutton onclientclick and postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I'm experiencing some weird behaviour when using a ASP.NET LinkButton with a OnClientClick-property.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="test" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem>test1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>test2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>test3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:LinkButton CssClass="button" ID="btnDeleteGroup" runat="server">
    <img src="cross.png" alt="delete-group" width="16" height="16" />
    <span><asp:Literal ID="lblDeleteGroup" runat="server" Text="Delete" /></span>
 </asp:LinkButton>
```

**Code-behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnDeleteGroup.OnClientClick = "return confirmAction('delete?');";
}
```

Without the OnClientClick, everything is fine.
With the OnClientClick, my LinkButton dissappears when a postback occurs (using the DropDownList).

In [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584747/postback-issue-in-asp-net), I've found a solution to set EnableViewState to false.
But the application I'm writing is multilingual so with EnableViewState set to "false", I'm also losing my translation.

```
if ( !Page.IsPostBack ) {
    // translate all form elements
    TranslationUI();
}
```

I rather not call this method outside the !Page.IsPostBack method because the TranslationUI-method() translates the form elements based on a database.

Comment: Wow that is very odd.. I can reproduce this as well.. In the resulting markup after the page posts back, the corresponding `<a>` tag for the link button does not contain any nested tags any longer. This is why it looks like it disappears..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some testing - I think the problem is, you need to ensure all nested tags within the LinkButton are serverside controls (I.e. either add `runat="server"` or change to related .net control, such as change the `img` tag to `asp:Image`). When there is non server-side markup within the LinkButton, there must be an issue with how it sets up its ViewState or something...

Anyway, the following works fine:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="test" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem>test1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>test2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>test3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:LinkButton CssClass="button" ID="btnDeleteGroup" runat="server">
    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgDeleteGroup" width="16" height="16" ImageUrl="cross.png" />
    <asp:Literal ID="lblDeleteGroup" runat="server" Text="Delete" />
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnDeleteGroup.OnClientClick = "return confirm('delete?');";
}
```