# popup control linkbutton prevent postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a popup control with a link button inside that is used to close the popup. The problem is that the link button (or image button in the code below) is causing a full postback which is not intended. Can anyone help? below is the code.

```
  <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlLogin" BehaviorID="logpop" Position="Bottom"
    TargetControlID="myLogin" PopupControlID="PanelLogin" runat="server">
</asp:PopupControlExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="PanelLogin" Style="position: absolute; display: none;" runat="server">
    <div style="border: solid 1px #808080; border-width: 1px 0px;">
        <div style="background: url(images/sprite.png) repeat-x 0px -200px;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Style="font-weight: bold;" Text="Login" />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" Style="background: url(images/sprite.png) no-repeat 0px -300px;"
                OnClientClick="$find('logpop').hide(); return false;" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: #f2f2f2; width: 300px; height: 150px;">
            My Content
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Have you tried this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2193556/618331

Comment: Akos, I donot have any control inside the link button (like in the post you mentioned).

Answer (score 2):

You are using it correctly, but I think there's an error in your jquery `$find`. Should be

```
$('#logpop').hide();
```

or

```
OnClientClick="$('#logpop').hide(); return false;"
```

Comment: That is `$find()` from Microsoft Ajax I guess. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397441.aspx

Comment: Can't use that, `.hide()` would fail.

Comment: Both the Codes work and do indeed close the popup the problem is there is a postback which I donot want. One thing I forgot to mention is that...the code is in a contentpage..which makes use of a Masterpage.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the button to a straight HTML link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$find('logpop').hide(); return false;"><img src="images/sprite.png" /></a>
```

You can adjust the display as needed, but this should be what you need.